# Loosing pointer after reading bytes

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, null, byte

I'm doing a project where to construct an object MyClass from received bytes. The byte string consists of an integer (4 bytes) followed by a message (5 bytes).

I have created a template class to be able to read multiple types with ease and also wrote a template specialisation function to handle the case of char arrays.

Here's the code that's copy pastable in a main.cpp file.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class ByteReaderT {
    public:

    static const char* read(const char* source, T& dest, size_t sz)
    {
            std::copy(source, source + sz, &dest);
            return source + sz;
        }

};

template<>
inline const char* ByteReaderT<char*>::read(const char* source, char*& dest, size_t sz)
{
    return std::copy(source, source + sz, dest);
}


#define DATA_SIZE 5

struct MyClass {

    int num;
    char* data;

    MyClass(): num(0), data(new char[DATA_SIZE]) {}

    void read(const char* str) {
        // data is still alive and well
        str = ByteReaderT<int>::read(str, num, sizeof(int));
        // data is gone (data = nullptr)
        // I need to reallocate memory with data = new char[DATA_SIZE];
        str = ByteReaderT<char*>::read(str, data, DATA_SIZE);
    }

};



int main()
{
    char received_arr[] = {
        '\x01', '\0', '\0', '\0', // bytes for num
        'r', 'e', 'c', 'v', ' ' // bytes for data
    };

    MyClass c;
    char* ptr = nullptr;

    c.read(received_arr);
    std::cout << c.num << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::string(c.data) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However in the `MyClass::read` function, my data pointer is reset to nullptr after reading the first 4 bytes for the number.

And I have no clue why this is happening. The template function `ByteReaderT<int>::read` shouldn't touch the data pointer.

I can always allocate memory again for data in MyClass::read before reading the 5 byte message but that's not clean because I shouldn't have to.

If anyone sees where it goes wrong it would be much appreciated because right now I'm stuck.

Comment: Can any of the downvoters pitch in, with the reason? At the very least, the question has [mcve], which is a rare sight on SO, nowadays.

Comment: I first separated the code into different blocks and then realised it was going to a pain to copy paste if somebody wants to compile it. That's probably the reason.

Comment: But still, it was passable as [mcve].. I know that I am quick on a draw, on downvoting, and scolding people, due to the lack of [mcve], but your example looked good. Apparently, some people are even quicker on the downvote button, than me :/

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius That's not minimal.  It contains a lot of irrelevant code.

Comment: @L.F. How do you define "a lot"? I would disagree on the statement that it has "a lot" of irrelevant code. It _might_ have some code, that isn't relevant, to the immediate issue, but maybe, one just wanted to demonstrate how `data` member was being used, don't you think? I am comparing such example, with the average question, on SO, which, typically, is either not minimal (having couple hundreds of lines, which has unclear relation, to the issue being observed), and/or not reproducible (you can't copy-paste it, and get it to compile).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I guess you are right, this one is above average ...  But a minimal reproducible example for this shouldn't really exceed 10 lines IMO ...

Comment: @L.F. If you know, what the problem is, you can make [mcve], that produces only said problem. But, at that point - you already know the answer, and don't need to ask a question.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I don't really think so, it should be possible to identify that `copy` is the problem via debugging.

Comment: @L.F. 1) "_it should be possible to identify that copy is the problem via debugging_" Yes (for some of us, it was apparent immediately, without even debugging), but the true question, was **why it was a problem**? 2) If all people knew how to use the debugger, and knew how to **interpret what they are seeing**, there would be no need for 90% of questions asked on SO. 3) What I forgot to mention, in my previous comment: remember, this is UB we are talking about. The behavior, might as well, changed to whatever they expected behavior was, if they tried to make the example smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You confused [`std::copy`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy).**

`std::copy` is an algorithm from `<algorithm>` library, which takes a pair of iterators as source and an iterator as the output. It will simply go through each element in the source range and copy contruct them at range starting with `output`.

Because you provided an `int` as output, you are only allowed to write a single element. Going further is Undefined Behaviour (which in your case seems to be overwriting `data` member).

Sample usage of `std::copy`:

```
std::vector<int> a {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::array<int, 5> b;
for(int n: b)
    std::cout << n << " "; //0 0 0 0 0
std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());
for(int n: b)
    std::cout << n << " "; //1 2 3 4 5
```

---

`std::memcpy` on the other hand will simply take the content of the memory at given place and put in the other place, which is what you wanted to achieve.

Sample usage:

```
int a = 5;
char[4] b;
std::memcpy(b, &a, 4);
```

Comment: Beat me to it, with the answer.. Even though, I knew that this had to be UB, I was having major brain farts, as to the reason for it. Had to debug through `std::copy`, while having memory window open, to notice it :/

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Had the same problem :D `std::copy` looks so well here

Comment: it works like a charm with std::memcpy. Thanks a lot